# Is it possible to drag a row from a JQGrid to a droppable area that isn't another JQGrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Hello
In the JQGrid demos the drag and drop facilities show how a row can be dragged form one grid and dropped on another. I would like to be able to drag a row (or more specifically a cell) onto a droppable element that isn't a grid. Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to drop the data on jsTree node the code is as below

```
tree.jstree({
    ...
     "dnd": {
        "drop_finish": function (data) {
            alert("some message");
        }

        }

    "plugins": [..., "dnd"]

});
```

Make sure that you are using class="jstree-drop" for the nodes